# Reading Packet Id from Byte

Tags: vb.net, ascii, byte, character

I have a packet that I need to send to a client with an ID of 255.  I've had no problems sending packets with IDs of 0, 1, and 2.  The ID has to be 255.  For some reason, after the translation has happened, both me with my server, and the client, get "63" for any Id greater than 127.

This is the code I am using:

```
Console.WriteLine(Asc(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Chr("255")))))
```

Now, This is an overly complicated version of what the server does.  You may consider this a bit unnecessary but the inverse functions performed are for your viewing reasons only.

Where it says "255" is the Packet Id I need sent in the format above.  As I said, anything larger than 127 returns "63".  Very annoying.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding.aspx):

*ASCIIEncoding corresponds to the Windows code page 20127. Because ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, ASCII characters are limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F.*

So you can't use that technique, because 255 is not a valid ASCII character.

Comment: Well, the server protocol I am working with requires this.  I'm creating my own server for the client to connect to.  Here is a link to the protocol details.

Comment: I doubt very much that it requires any ASCII conversion.  The link is only referring to hex values, some of which are greater than 0x7F. ASCII is only defined for values between 0x00 and 0x7F. See the ASCII table: http://www.klcconsulting.net/ascii.htm

Comment: From what I've determined, the packets are identified by the first byte, which, after being converted to a string, is a character with the exact ASCII value of required packet ID.  Could it have anything to do with the fact that the client is Java?